# Empty red circle in Android notification status bar!

Tags: java, android, notifications, statusbar

When I have a status bar notification with a number inside, **it shows the number fine**. But later if I show another notification to **replace** this one, with **no number**, it shows an **empty red circle**. This circle shouldn't be there. How do I remove the red circle? See image here: http://jump.fm/UYHGV

I've already tried:

```
notification.number = 0;
```

and

```
notification.number = -1;
```

And forget about canceling notifications first. Since there's no way to query the notification service for existing notifications, I can't detect if the previous one needs to be updated. If I would cancel every time I notify, the user will see the status bar flashing once in a while, which is annoying.

Please advise.

Emmanuel

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hope this help http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=7891

Comment: Thanks dude, this at least confirms that it's a known bug. They said they'll fix it in the next version. For now I'll just keep my previous notification around, and simply cancel it first if it's different from the new notification.